# Sorting a double array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator

This is my unsorted array:

```
P  B    A 
5  125  400
2  102  145
3  56   200
6  65   200
7  30   200
4  148  300
1  135  0
```

This is what my current array has after I sorted it this is the output I get

```
P  B    A 
1  135  0 
2  102  145 
3  56   200 
6  65   200 
7  30   200 
4  148  300 
5  125  400
```

And I would like the output to look like this

```
P  B    A 
1  135  0 
2  102  145
7  30   200 
3  56   200 
6  65   200 
4  148  300 
5  125  400
```

This is currently my code

```
Arrays.sort(myArr, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);
    }
});
```

Comment: And the problem with your code/your question is...

Comment: How can an array have characters (PBA) and ints? How are the ints stored in the array?

Comment: Do you want it sorted by A then B?

Comment: it doesn't thats the output

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: @IfrahimHernandez please do not forget to mark the question as "solved".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to further specify the `Comparator`. At the moment, you are only sorting the array by the 3rd element.

```
Arrays.sort(myArr, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        int ret = Integer.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);
        // if the entries are equal at index 2, compare index 1
        if (0 == ret) {
            ret = Integer.compareTo(o1[1], o2[1]);
        }
        return (ret);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are storing your `int` arrays in another array, presumably in a `int[][]`.  You are attempting to enforce a relationship between the 3 elements of your inner arrays.  In an object-oriented language like Java, it is better to define a class to store the 3 values together, and then to create a one-dimensional array to store the objects.

```
public class My3Values {
    private int p, b, a;
    // Constructor(s), getters go here
}
```

(It doesn't have to be called `My3Values`, it's just for example.)

Then you can define your `Comparator` class as a `Comparator<My3Values>`.

Second, you are currently ignoring the `B` value that means something for your sort.  Add code that considers the `B` value if the `A` values are identical.

```
int comp = Integer.compare(o1.getA(), o2.getA());
if (comp == 0)
{
    comp = Integer.compare(o1.getB(), o2.getB());
}
return comp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle case where comparing second row will return `0` (equal values) and in that case return result of comparing values from first columns.

So your code can be chanced do something like:

```
Arrays.sort(myArr, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        int result = Integer.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);
        if (result != 0) 
            return result;
        else 
            return Integer.compare(o1[1], o2[1]);
    }
});
```

---

But if it is possible that you will want to compare more than one column and if you want to easily create different orders you should create separate comparator for each column.

In Java 8 you can rewrite comparator like

```
Comparator<int[]> secondColumnt = new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);
    }
}
```

by writing it as

```
Comparator<int[]> secondColumnt = Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row[2]);
```

so lets also create comparator for first column

```
Comparator<int[]> firstColumnt = Comparator.comparingInt(row -> row[1]);
```

Now since Java 8 we can create comparators from already existing comparators using [`thenComparing`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) method.

So if we want to create comparator which will first compare values in second columns and if they are equal comparator for first first column we can write it as

```
Comparator<int[]> secondThenFirstColumn = secondColumnt.thenComparing(firstColumnt);
```

So your final code can look like

```
Arrays.sort(myArr, secondThenFirstColumn);
```

or

```
Arrays.sort(myArr, secondColumnt.thenComparing(firstColumnt));
```

or if you don't want to create separate predefined comparators

```
Arrays.sort(myArr, Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(row -> row[2]).thenComparingInt(row -> row[2]));
```